# Firebase events not showing NAME attribute

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have uploaded an app with firebase analytics, however, the SELECT_CONTENT events are not showing "Not set" as name, instead of the name i specified during development.

[image: Firebase Console Events]

here's one of the events i set on code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "4");
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "ClickedShareSocialMedia");
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set the FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE parameter.

You get reporting on both the CONTENT_TYPE (i.e. category) and the ITEM_NAME.  The "(not set)" you are seeing is in reference to the CONTENT_TYPE.  Once you specify a CONTENT_TYPE, you'll be able to drill into each type of content to see the most important items in each category.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, now another quick question, now content type shows perfectly, but under that content type, i dont see the names of the events, just the ID (numbers) that i set for each event. should the ID be set as the names of the events?

Comment: If you look at the API docs for SELECT_CONTENT, you'll see that it suggests ITEM_ID as the parameter you should pass : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#constants

Comment: strange that in the getting started guide ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events ) which i used for setting up the project, is using the 3 of them

Comment: You can supply any and all parameters that make sense for you, but that report in particular is fueled by the two.  The full set of 25 parameters is available for use in the audience builder or in BigQuery.

Comment: Perfect!! that makes sense, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will just add small link, direct link what params could be for SELECT_CONTENT is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#SELECT_CONTENT

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41396856/6144372 Please help!

Comment: @SteveGanem  so I think firebase needs to mention some were in a document because I can't find that anywhere in the firebase event document.

otherwise that's maybe a bug of firebase because may user facing that kind of issue.