# 'FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD' is failing to save the 'value' along with 'Event name` in the console

Tags: android, firebase, bundle, firebase-analytics

I'm using this code to analyse the sign_up method user is using:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD, "sign_up_method");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SIGN_UP, bundle);
```

as soon as the user sign up, above given code is supposed to save the event in the Firebase console.

**The problem** is that the event is getting created but the there's nothing under the `value` column, i.e., `sign_up_method` is not getting shown.

Here's a snapshot from the console (event name: `sign_up` is there but in place of the `sign_up_method`, there is a `-`):

[image]

What's going wrong here?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked the same question from the Firebase Support Team and they told me that

> Unfortunately, not all parameters are represented directly in your
>   Analytics reports. It is only available on a subset of suggested
>   events. But they can be used as filters in Audience definitions for
>   every report.  They are also included in data exported to BigQuery if
>   your app is linked to a BigQuery project.

So, either link your app to BigQuery or get satisfied with what Firebase has to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [Firebase Analytics docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#public-static-final-string-sign_up) for this. Looks like you are incorrectly setting the parameter as `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD`

It should be FirebaseAnalytics.Param.METHOD instead